# C method Fread() equivalency in C#

Tags: c#, c

I am working on LOTUS Notes API, during the process i came to a point where the fucntio in like this ,

```
bytesRead = fread (Buffer, 1, (WORD) Length, hCDFile);
```

Now i found some C# equivalent method like , which runs inside a while loop .At the first iteration the method seems working fine ( the result are same when i debug c version of code and C# version). But in second iteration say suppose the values of dwLengthHost =35, 
before this method i called another method

`NSFDUMPReadFromFile(hCDFile, ref RecordTypeCanonicalPtr, sizeof (ushort))` which calls the `fread` function and give value `RecordTypeCanonicalPtr=149` . But after that when same method is called later the `RecordTypeCanonicalPtr` and `dwLengthHost`  values changes automatically .

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
public static extern UInt32 fread(ref IntPtr Buffer, uint Size, uint Count, IntPtr Stream);

private bool NSFDUMPReadFromFile(IntPtr hCDFile,
                                        ref IntPtr Buffer,
                                        UInt32 Length)
{
    UInt32 bytesRead = NotesApi.fread(ref Buffer, 1, (uint)Length, hCDFile);
    /* Read bytes from the file */ 
    if (bytesRead == Length)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look like you need to use [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0bs3w9t.aspx)

You can create it by using [`File.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.open.aspx)

Exactly same behavior as:

```
bytesRead = fread (Buffer, 1, (WORD) Length, hCDFile);
```

should provide following C# code

```
bytesRead = file.Read(Buffer, 0, Length)
```

full example might be following

```
using(file = File.Open("test.bin", FileMode.Open))
{
    var length = 256;
    var buffer = new byte[length];
    var bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, length);
}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your reply .
actually i have to work with pointers and this method is used for different conditions. In some cases it returns databuffer , some cased record type. so dont think above method fits in all cases.

Comment: Are you working with IntPtr or with pointer for cursor position in file?
If you are working with IntPtr there is no method for reading file that fits you purpose from the box. But you anyway can use suggested way to read file, only after that you need to copy byte array into unmanaged memory using [`Marshal.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy.aspx)

Comment: Hi all actually i found mscrolib.dll which helped me out.